Buildroot with support for float128 on SAMA5D2 (Cortex-A5)
I'm trying to port an aplication that uses float128 (previously running on an arm64) to a board with SAMA5D2 (Cortex-A5) but can't seem to find a way to enable support for float 128.
After looking around on google seems that float128 is not supported on all architectures, but for arm32 (this processor) I couldn't find a clear answer, hopefully it supports it.
My question is, what flags/packages do I need to enable for buildroot build a toolchain that supports float128?
I already tried hard and soft floating point strategy (on the target options) but without success.
The closest I found to remediate the situation was using boost multiprecision libraries, but requires quite a few changes and was hoping to not having to take that route

GCC doesn't have emulation for 128-bit floats on hardware that doesn't support them. ARM32 doesn't have instructions for 128-bit floating point operations, so GCC doesn't offer it either. The GCC documentation for float128 doesn't mention ARM so that should be a hint already, and you can check with the compiler that long double is 8 bytes.
You will need to find a library that emulates 128-bit floating points in software. But it will be quite expensive, to the level that a multiprecision library (like gmp) may give better performance.

That was what I was suspecting, thank you for the confirmation
